# Dia della donna or Dia delle donne?

Tags: translation, name

Was yesterday called dia della donna or dia delle donne? I was unsure which was the correct name.

Comment: "Dia" is Spanish for "day", the Italian correspondent would be "giorno/giornata".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Italian the 8th of March holiday is called: "la festa della donna".

The translation of a "woman's day" means literally: "il giorno della donna", but in Italian we use more "la festa della donna ".

The phrase you wrote in your question is in Spanish I guess...